# Grep with BBEdit

Tags: grep, bbedit

I do have one large text file with lot of the following patterns;

```
because of,this 
or that,has 
or,not
```

Of course I want to change the following

```
because of, this
or that, has
or, not
```

To make myself clear: i would like to insert a `space` after each `,`

How can i do that with BBEdit Find/Replace/Grep?

[image]

Find works ok with

```
[\,](\w)
```

but i can't figure out the coresponding part for replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I complicates matters.

Pattern like `Letter,Letter` can also be found with `,\b`.

\b is at the beginning or end of a word. \b in a regular expression means "word boundary".

The replacement is then done with `,_`

Nota Bene: `_` is a "Space" after `,`

Answer (score 1):

```
Find: (\,)(\w)
Replace: \1 \2
```

Note: You need to hit the spacebar between \1 and \2. Works on my computer with BBedit v13

Answer (score 0):

you could just replace all commas with a comma-space and then replace all space-space with space